# Angular 6 with steam-passport - Auth Guard Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, passport.js, steam

I'm using steam-passport to loggin.
So basically, I go to `localhost/auth/steam`, this redirect me to steam service, then go back to `localhost/auth/steam/return`, and from there, I got my `req.user` as expected :

```
router.get('/auth/steam/return',
  passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: 'http://localhost:4200/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/'); --angular port application
    console.log(req.user) -- I have all my datas
  });
```

Again, when I open my brower and I go to `localhost/api/isLoggedIn`, I have my `req.user` as expected:

```
router.get('/api/isLoggedIn', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    console.log(req.user)
    if (req.user.db) {
      res.json({user: req.user.db, success: true})
      return
    }
  }
  res.json({success: false})
})
```

The issue is when I'm using it with Angular.
I'm forced to do a `window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/auth/steam";` when I click on the loggin button. And again, I have my datas when the steam service answered to me.

But when I'm trying to access it from Angular:

```
isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    let obs = this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/isLoggedIn').subscribe(data => {
      return JSON.parse(data._body).success -- this is always FALSE!
    })
  }
```

How to manage the issue? From the brower, it's ok but from Angular, it's look like it's not the same guy who clicked on the button ahah.

Thanks for any future answer.

EDIT:
I invenstigate a bit, and I don't have the same session when I go over the brower to  `/api/isLoggedIn` and when I make an http get request from Angular, how to link both?

session id for browser : `EvbuWUZ7vceCxHsm7npb6572bLe-1lRC`

session id for Angular : it change every time I make the request..

Answer (score 0):

Your `isAuthenticated()` function is always returns `undefined` (which can be treated as false).

Look into your function. Your function is not returning anything. The return statement is inside of async function.

Try this.

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/isLoggedIn')
      .pipe(
        map(data => !!JSON.parse(data._body).success)
      )
  }
```